# Android 3 linked values

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array, maps

What would be the best way to store multiple 3 linked values (String, String, Boolean)? Like in a HashMap for example.

I need to:

- save them in SharedPreferences
- load them of sp (of course)
- change at least the last value dynamically
- get all items where the last value is true (for example)

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

- Store it on preferences
- Store it in a database
- Save a file on disk

If you want to proceed with preferences I will suggest you to convert the 3 value format to a Json format and store it in preferences as json.

```
{"value1":"value", "value2":"value", "value3":"value"}
```

or

```
{"data":"some data",
 "link":{
         "data":"other linked data",
         "link":{...}
        }
}
```

This kind of data is also stored perfectly in a noSQL database. But if you do not want to add a database at all to your project, maybe you can have a look to some noSQL libraries like [SimpleNoSQL](https://github.com/Jearil/SimpleNoSQL) (it indeed uses a database behind the scenes, but abstracts you very well from it) or [Realm](http://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/) (it stores on disk).

Comment: Mhh a json seems okay, I used it befor and some googleing implies a simple implementation! Is there a way to change only one value inside the json object? Or do I need to recreate the whole json?

Comment: Sure! You can change the data in the json (the class is JSONObject#put(name, value). See http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html